# Is there a 'superclass' for Iterable and a regular array?

Tags: java

I'm using an enhanced for loop, and it looks something like this:

```
public void addItems (Iterable<Item> items) {
    for (Item item : items) {
        addItem(item);
    }
}

public void addItems(Item[] items) {
    for(Item item : items) {
        addItem(item);
    }
}
```

Using the `Iterable` allows me to use `List` et al., but I have to have a separate method for regular arrays. Is there some way to combine this (without using reflection, or increasing line count, or creating garbage), so I don't have to duplicate code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could overload the method (Preferred)

```
public void addItems(Item[] items) {
   addItems(Arrays.asList(items));
}
```

or convert to a List each time you call the method.

```
addItems(Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3}));
```

The second method is less than optimal.  As Sticky has mentioned:

> I'd imagine there's more duplication with Arrays.asList all over the
>   place rather than the 3 lines in my class.

Comment: Thanks, see jtahlborn's (identical) answer for an extra question.

Comment: @Sticky, yeah he was a hair quicker than me

Comment: @Sticky I proposed another option, but I think its not optimal.  I don't see any other way and really there is no harm in having an overloaded method.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I'm really just trying to make the public interface as dumbed down as possible. I'd imagine there's more duplication with `Arrays.asList` all over the place rather than the 3 lines in my class.

Comment: @Sticky exactly `I'd imagine there's more duplication with Arrays.asList all over the place rather than the 3 lines in my class.`

Answer (score 5):

```
public void addItems(Item[] items) {
    addItems(Arrays.asList(items));
}
```

Comment: @jlordo Yes because `List` implements `Iterable<E>`

Comment: Thanks. That should work? But is it going to create garbage? (I've updated the question to include that as a criterion)

Comment: @Sticky no this is simply method overloading

Comment: @Sticky No, because the List that `Arrays.asList` returns is just a wrapper around the array

Comment: @KevinBowersox: Yeah, I got confused by his method names. I thought he was trying to insert into the given list/array.

Comment: Does this mean there's no way of avoiding having two methods, then?